# How to unwind an array field which further contains an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi i have an `userAnswer schema` which looks like this

```
var userAnswer = mongoose.Schema({
'questionId' : { 'type' : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 'ref': 'Question'},
'userId' : { 'type': mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 'ref' : 'User'},
'score' : 1 
})
```

Then an `userAttempt schema` which contains the attempts regarding to this question

```
var userAttempt = mongoose.Schema({
'userAnswerId' : { 'type' : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 'ref' : 'UserAnswer'},
'attemptData' : [{ 
    'userInputMCQ' : String,
    'time' : Date 
    }],
})
```

And last `usersnapshots schema` which saves snapshots regarding for each element in `attemptData` field of `userAttempt Schema`

it looks like this

```
var userAttemptSnapshot= mongoose.Schema({
userAttemptDataId : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
count : {type: Number, default: 1},
userData :[ {
    value: String,
    timeOfCreation : { type : Date, default : Date.now }
    }]
}, 
   {    timestamps: true    }
);
```

Now i want to fetch all `data` regarding to a `question` attempt in such a way that all `documents` in `attempData` field of `UserAttempt Schema`
which is

```
 'attemptData' : [{ 
    'userInputMCQ' : String,
    'time' : Date 
    }],
```

fetched as individual `attempt` with their respective `snapshots` using `aggregation`

My `aggregation query` is

```
db.useranswers.aggregate([ 
{ $match : {  'questionId' : ObjectId("5a2dfefd6dc3de029e488961"),'userId' :ObjectId("5a2cea6d6dc3de029e488814") }},
{ '$lookup' : {from: "userattempts",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "userAnswerId",
    as: "attempts"}},
{ '$unwind' : '$attempts'},
{'$unwind' : '$attempts.attemptData'}
//after this stage i will use lookup to get snapshot data but i dont get those attempts as individual documents so that i could use lookup here
})
```

*Edit:*
My `userAnswer` collection is

```
{ 
    "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359244781a45bcc98fcb") , 
    "userId":ObjectId("5a2cea6d6dc3de029e488814"),
    "questionId": ObjectId("5a631937e2509a3288171c37"),
}
```

`UserAttempt` collection is

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef24"),
    "attemptData":[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef23"),
        "userInputMCQ" : "0"
        "timeOfCreation" : ISODate("2018-07-18T18:11:54.855+05:30"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b4f35bb04a7251ebcabef27"),
        "userInputMCQ" : "0",
        "timeOfCreation" : ISODate("2018-07-18T18:12:35.765+05:30"),
    } ]
}

UserAttemptSnapshot collection is
{
    "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef25"),
    "userAttemptId":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef23"),
    "count" : 2,
    "userData" : [ { 
                     'value' : "Some String" ,
                     "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef26")  
                   },
                   { 
                     'value' : "Some String" ,
                     "_id": ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef27")  
                   } ]
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef25"),
    "userAttemptId":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef27"),
    "count" : 1,
    "userData" : [ { 
                     'value' : "Some String" ,
                     "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabeaee")  
                   },
                 ]
}
```

I want output like this

```
{
     "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359244781a45bcc98fcb") , 
    "userId":ObjectId("5a2cea6d6dc3de029e488814"),
    "questionId": ObjectId("5a631937e2509a3288171c37"),
    "attemptData": {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef23"),
        "userInputMCQ" : "0"
        "timeOfCreation" : ISODate("2018-07-18T18:11:54.855+05:30"),
        "userAttemptId" : ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef23"),
        "count" : 2,
        "userData" : [ { 
                 'value' : "Some String" ,
                 "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef26")  
               },
               { 
                 'value' : "Some String" ,
                 "_id": ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef27")  
               } ]
    },
},
{
     "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359244781a45bcc98fcb") , 
    "userId":ObjectId("5a2cea6d6dc3de029e488814"),
    "questionId": ObjectId("5a631937e2509a3288171c37"),
    "attemptData": {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5b4f35bb04a7251ebcabef27"),
          "userInputMCQ" : "0",
          "timeOfCreation" : ISODate("2018-07-18T18:12:35.765+05:30"),
          "userAttemptId":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabef27"),
          "count" : 1,
          "userData" : [ { 
                 'value' : "Some String" ,
                 "_id":ObjectId("5b4f359204a7251ebcabeaee")  
               },
             ]
    }  
}
```

Comment: can you post the sample collections and the output... Which version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: @Winzlet i have edited my question with collections and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

```
db.useranswers.aggregate([ 
{"$lookup":{
    "from": "userattempts",
    "let": {"id":"$_id"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$$id","$userAnswerId"]}}},
      {"$unwind":"$attemptData"},
      {"$lookup":{
        "from": "userattemptsnapshots",
        "localField": "attemptData._id",
        "foreignField":"userAttemptId",
        "as": "attemptData.attemptsnapshot"
      }},
      {"$unwind":"$attemptData.attemptsnapshot"},
      {"$group":{
         "_id":"$userAnswerId",
         "attemptData":{
            "$push":"$attemptData"
         }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "attempts"
 }},
{"$unwind":"$attempts"},
])
```

Update 3.4 Version

```
db.useranswers.aggregate([ 
{"$lookup":{
    "from": "userattempts",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField":"userAnswerId",
    "as": "attempts"
}},
{"$unwind":"$attempts"},
{"$unwind":"$attempts.attemptData"},
{"$lookup":{
    "from": "userattemptsnapshots",
    "localField": "attempts.attemptData._id",
    "foreignField":"userAttemptId",
    "as": "attempts.attemptData.attemptsnapshot"
}},
{"$unwind":"$attempts.attemptData.attemptsnapshot"}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am using version 3.4, its works fine in 3.6. Can u plz help me out with version 3.4.

Comment: Yw. Added a 3.4 version. Give it a try. If you get no data after second unwind it is mostly you don't have any matching attempt data. Use $unwind with preserveNullAndEmptyArrays option. Something like  `{ $unwind: { path: "$attempts.attemptData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }`